# How to filter date range data in timestamp with specific time from and to?

Tags: postgresql

Assuming, I have data as below:

```
2021-09-10  09:00:00.000+00
2021-09-20  10:00:00.000+00
2021-09-20  11:00:00.000+00
```

I want to filter date range from `2021-09-20 10am to 2021-09-21 6pm`? How can I write query to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a range condition in the WHERE clause:

```
select *
from the_table
where the_column >= timestamp '2021-09-20 10:00:00'
  and the_column  < timestamp '2021-09-21 18:00:00'
```

`timestamp` literals are specified using the ISO standard for date/time literals. So the time part needs to be written in 24hour format.

It's not clear from your question if you want to *include* rows at `18:00:00` or if that should be the upper bound which is excluded. The above assumes the latter.

Comment: The format from my pgsql is `timestamp without time zone` as **UTC**

Comment: `timestamp` columns don't have "a format"

Comment: Here sameple data from my pgsql: ``2021-06-27 23:42:10.641654``

Comment: Sure, that will work. You could simply try it and convince yourself.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   table
WHERE  column BETWEEN '2021-09-20 10:00:00'::timestamp
                 AND '2021-09-21 18:00:00'::timestamp;
```